# Create a list of integer elements from list of objects

Tags: python

I need to create list of non-duplicated integer elements from list of objects.

For example:
There is an object with two attributes: 'id' and 'other_id':

```
first = [elem.id for elem in objects_list]
second = [elem.other_id for elem in objects_list]
print first
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
print second
[4,5,6,7,9]
```

Now I can create two list containing that two attributes from all objects like this:

```
first = [elem.id for elem in objects_list]
first.extend(elem.other_id for elem in objects_list if elem.other_id not in first)
print first
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]
```

Is there any way to do this in shorter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `set`:

```
sorted(set().union(first, second)) #returns a sorted list of unique items
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> first = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> second = [4,5,6,7,9]
>>> sorted(set(first + second))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

If the original order matters:

```
>>> first = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> seen = set(first)
>>> first += [x for x in second if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
>>> first
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

For large lists the set approach is going to be efficient as sets provide `O(1)` lookup, for tiny lists your approach is also okay.

Comment: An alternative to `+`'ing the lists is use `set().union(first, second)`

Comment: @JonClements Good idea, that is better.